# Edge (chromium) requires a non-UWP binary for NativeMessaging?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Edge Legacy required an UWP native messaging host application. 
Can this same UWP native messaging host application be used for the chromium based Edge, or is it **required** to use a Win32 host binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pieter,

Currently, the answer is "No" because a UWP's executable has a scrambled path when it is deployed to a Windows 10 machine.  This makes it relatively impossible to know its destination path in order for you to specify it in your native-message-host manifest.

Answer (score -1):

Native messaging in MS Edge Chromium extension will work in a similar way as it works for Google Chrome extensions.

In order to register a native messaging host the application must install a manifest file that defines the native messaging host configuration. Below is an example of the manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "com.my_company.my_application",
    "description": "My Application",
    "path": "C:\\Program Files\\My Application\\chrome_native_messaging_host.exe",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
        "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
    ]
}
```

The location of the manifest file depends on the platform.

On Windows, the manifest file may be located anywhere in the file system. The application installer must create registry key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Edge\NativeMessagingHosts\com.my_company.my_application

or

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.my_company.my_application

and set default value of that key to the full path to the manifest file. For example, using the following shell command:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Edge\NativeMessagingHosts\com.my_company.my_application" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\path\to\nmh-manifest.json" /f
```

or using the following .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Edge\NativeMessagingHosts\com.my_company.my_application]
@="C:\\path\\to\\nmh-manifest.json"
```

When Microsoft Edge looks for native messaging hosts, the 32-bit registry is queried first, then the 64-bit registry.

To get more information, you can refer to the link below.

[Native Messaging For Edge Chromium extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/native-messaging)

To know the difference in the approach for Edge legacy extensions, you can refer to the link below.

[Native messaging in Microsoft Edge legacy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging)

Comment: Deepak-MSFT,

I believe you did not answered Pieter's question.  Also, there is a gap in this new chromium architecture since it requires our native-message-host manifest to specify the executable's path.  And we know that UWP scrambles the path when the user installs it.